# Check if parent post is sticky on attachment page?

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, sticky-post, featured-post

I use this code on post template (single.php) to check if current post is sticky:

```
<?php
if ( is_sticky() )
echo 'Post is sticky.';
?>
```

But it is not working on attachment page template (image.php). I wish to check if parent post is sticky on attachment page of post featured image.

How to check if parent post is sticky on attachment page (image.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post parent can be accessed by `$post->post_parent`. The ID of the post parent is retrieved, so can try something like this

```
$parent_ID = $post->post_parent;
if( is_sticky( $parent_ID ) ) {

    // DO SOMETHING IF POST PARENT IS STICKY

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. Could you please look at another related question [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173334/show-prev-and-next-post-links-on-attachment-page]?